# How to encode unicode surrogate pairs, to write to file

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, surrogate-pairs

I'm creating an compression / encryption program that utilises (nearly) all unicode characters, and then writes the data to a file. However, to write to the file, I need to encode the characters to bytes. However, when I do so, It gives this error:

```
unicodeencodeerror: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udd7d' in position 1323: surrogates not allowed
```

I've tried all of the built-in python codecs, none of them work, except for 'utf-7', however, this simply encodes the unicode to base64, which defeats the object of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
file = open(str(file_name.capitalize()) + ".Unicode_File","wb")
    file.write(unicode_madness.encode("utf-8"))
    file.close()
```

I expect it to write the variable 'unicode_madness' to the file, which it does, however sometimes it tries to use a surrogate unicode character.

To resolve this, I either need to be able to avoid the surrogate characters (while keeping the compression lossless), or I need to find out which unicode characters use surrogates, and I can adjust the program accordingly.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Don't use surrogate characters for your encryption: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+D800_to_U+DFFF. Most relevantly: "The official Unicode standard says that no UTF forms, including UTF-16, can encode these code points."

Comment: After what unicode characters do surrogates appear? I'm using chr() / ord() to encrypt the data, what numbers should I avoid?

Comment: The range is given in the URL.

Comment: What ord() number is that?

Comment: Encode Unicode (str) to UTF-8 (bytes), *then* encrypt.